# Word formation with the nominal suffix -tion: when and why do we insert an "a"?

Tags: suffixes, word-formation

Recently, a colleague became flustered when she used *orientate* instead of *orient*. She says she frequently makes this sort of "back formation error" because of the nominal form, which is *orientation*. This has gotten me thinking about how nominal forms are created.

Certainly, it is unambiguous for words that end in -ate or -ite (I think):

> **hibernate** becomes **hibernation**
>   **ignite** becomes **ignition**

And some words, you need the "a" to pronounce the word easily:

> **cancel** becomes **cancellation**
>   **affirm** becomes **affirmation**

But what about other words? Is there a difference in meaning between the suffixes -ation and -tion? Is there a rule about when to insert an a, and when to leave it out?

> **prevent** becomes **prevention**
>   **inspect** becomes **inspection**
>   **prohibit** becomes **prohibition**
>   but
>   **indent** becomes **indentation**  (not *indention)
>   **cohabit** becomes **cohabitation**  (not *cohabition)
>   **orient** becomes **orientation**  (not *oriention)

Do words that have the -ation suffix have an archaic -ate form? Are they related somehow?

NB: I know that *orientate* is considered a "real" word, but its use is considered uneducated by the hoity-toity academics with whom I work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Latin suffix *-io*, stem *-ion-*, is usually added to the supine stem ( ~= past participle stem) of a Latin verb, in order to form a noun of action (meaning "x-ing"). It is sometimes also added to other stems, but usually not. The verb *vocare* ("to call"), present stem *voca-*, supine stem *voca-t-*, gets *vocatio* ("calling"); the stem of that noun is *vocation-*, which is what our suffix was based on.

Because the regular suffix for the supine stem / past participle is *-t-* in Latin, we often see *-tion*; but compare also *miss-ion, fus-ion, cohes-ion, inflex-ion, etc.*. The same suffix can also be found with non-supine stems, though less frequently so, like *rebellion, legion*, etc.

---

Now how can we predict what comes before *-ion* in English? I don't have a neat system based on tight rules, but perhaps I can give a few general directions.

What we could do is try and think of a cognate verb, as you have been rightly doing. Does this verb end in vowel + *t* or vowel + *te*? If yes, it is probably based on a (real or reconstructed) Latin supine stem; then *-ion* can come right after the *t*, as in *inhibit, complete, migrate*.

---

And what if the verb does not end in vowel + *t(e)*? Then you need to know whether or not its stem is a supine stem in Latin. There is no way to know this except by consulting a Latin dictionary. But there are some unreliable rules.

Irregular supine stems most often end on *s* or *x*, so verbs like *flex* (from verbal stem *flect-*, "to bend") and *fuse* (from verbal stem *fund-*, "to pour") contain the supine stems *flex-* and *fus-*, leading to *inflexion* and *fusion*. But *vex-* and *pos-* are not supine stems, so *vexation* and *position*, from supine stems *vexa-t-* and *pos-i-t-* (the *i* is probably a fused theme vowel).

There are many supine stems that end on *-pt-* or *-ct-*, like *act-* and *rupt-*, leading to *action* and *eruption*.

Verbs ending on *-nt* are nearly always based on the present-participle stem *-nt-*, and so cannot get *-ion* right after *nt*; but there are a few supine stems on *-nt-* as well, mainly *vent-* and *tent-*, leading to *-vention* and *-tention*.

But there are also some nominal ("noun") stems that can get *-ion*, as mentioned before, like *mens,* "mind", stem *ment-,* leading to *mention*; and *dens* "tooth", stem *dent-*.

---

*Cohabitation* is an apparent exception. But both *habē-re* ("to have") and *habita-re* ("to inhabit") exist as verbs. *Habitare* was actually formed based on the supine stem *habit-* from *habēre*; then a new supine stem was formed based on this new verb, *habitat-*. And so we have *pro-hibi-t-ion* and *co-habi-t-at-ion*.

Normally it isn't very functional in Latin to make a new verb based on the supine stem of another, since you already have the original verb; but it is sometimes done, often to add a sense of frequency or intensity, and so two supine forms may come to exist. Usually *a* is then added after the supine stem to turn it into a new verbal stem, because *a* indicates a causative verb, i.e. a verb that means not "to do x" but "to cause someone to do x" (with nominal stems, "to turn into x, to affect with x", or simply to turn any nominal stem into a verb). So *fugere* = "to flee"; *fugare* = "to make flee, to drive away"; *donum* = "gift", *donare* = "to present as a gift" (or simply "to give").

Cf. *haerē-re ("to stick") => hae-s-us (past participle, "stuck") => hae-s-ere => hae-s-it-us => hae-s-it-are => hae-s-it-at-us => hae-s-it-at-io =>>* hesitation. Notice that the same supine suffix has been added thrice: *s, it, at* (the *t* was turned into an *s* after certain verbal stems; the *i* and the *a* are theme vowel and causative vowel, respectively). And so we have co-he-s-ion and he-s-it-at-ion, both from the same verbal stem *haer(e)-*.

---

So it is theoretically possible to add *-ation* after any supine stem; but that is usually not done, because just *-ion* is shorter. After any stem that isn't a supine stem, just adding *-ion* is unusual, so we will usually have to turn it into a (real or hypothetical) verb first with *-a-*, then add the *-t-*, then *-ion* — i.e. we have to add *-ation*. But, as mentioned above, there are many exceptions, where *-ion* can be added directly to non-supine stems; however, this is a fixed set of words that mostly already existed in that approximate form in Latin.

Comment: Excellent. You have covered the gamut, but you had me at supine stem. And I wish I could give you +5 for the hesitation example. Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: So basically, what you say is:

This construction comes from supine verbs in Latin, but when it comes to non-supine verbs, you haven't the foggiest *why* people sometimes add -a, and at other times just -tion.

Doesn't seem like it much answers the OP's question, to me.

Comment: @KylePearson: Uh, no. The English suffix *-ion* can only be added to supine stems; whenever we have a word on *-ion* in which the suffix comes immediately after a non-supine stem, this suffix was added in Latin, not in English. The suffix is not productive in English in such cases; we have no choice but to add *-ation* to those stems. If the word was formed in Latin, both formations were possible, though you will usually see *-ion* with supine stems and *-ation/-ition* with non-supine stems, the many exceptions notwithstanding.

Comment: @KylePearson: But I agree that this leaves open the causes of the many exceptions. As to the addition of *-ion* to non-supine stems, this is a question about Latin, not English, since I believe it nearly always happened in Latin. As to *-ation* after supine stems, some of those instances were also formed in Latin; others were perhaps formed in English—and I have not explained their origin, as you say. But how many of those are there anyway? It would be interesting if you could come up with a few (I expect there to be few). I didn't quite understand your hypothesis, but it could be worth while.

Comment: From a phonological standpoint, the "exceptions" aren't exceptions at all;  they clearly adhere to basic rules about emphasis and cadence, and these rules are usually quite easily intuited, if not explained.

Answer (score 0):

While "orientate" may be a back formation, it has been considered a legitimate word since the 1820's;  it is often used in orienteering and surveys, and is a  perfectly acceptable alternative to the verb, "orient".

The insertion of an "-a" or "-i" suffix between "-tion" and the preceding syllable is a consequence of two things:

- The relative emphasis of the preceding syllable (is it lightly emphasized, strongly emphasized, or de-emphasized?)
- and the final consonant/vowel array.

If the final syllable is anything but the most strongly emphasized syllable in the word, then generally "-a" or "-i" will be added to provide a strong vowel sound just before the "-tion" suffix.  This is necessary because most standard nouns in English carry a light emphasis on the next-to-last syllable.

If the final syllable is strong, or if the next-to-last syllable is strong -- as in "prevent", or "indent" (i.e. -- is a two-syllable verb form) or "prohibit" or "inhibit" (i.e. -- a three-syllable verb form) -- then an "-a" is not needed ("indention" and "indentation" were established as words right about the same time, although "indention" did come a little after "indentation";  both are listed as legitimate words in dictionaries, and neither is considered a back-formation of the other by the online etymological dictionary).

"Cohabit" is a ringer because "habitate" is the original root, from "habitare" in Latin, so "cohabit" is the actual back formation, while "cohabitate" and "cohabitation" are the original forms.