# How do Latin etymons that end in English in *-tion* nearly always name a process?

Tags: latin

I don't think the emboldening is correct, because [*-ing* gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314335) name a process. See https://english.stackexchange.com/a/444498. *-tion* just names a result of that process. What do you think?

> In English and many other languages the word for transla-
> tion is a two-headed beast. ‘A translation’ names a product
> – any work translated from some other language; whereas
> ‘translation’, without an article, names a process – the process
> by which ‘a translation’ comes to exist. This kind of double
> meaning is not a problem for speakers of languages that pos-
> sess regular sets of terms referring both to a process and to
> the product of that process (as do most Western European
> languages). Speakers of English, French and so forth are quite
> accustomed to negotiating such duplicity and can play games

Page 21

> with it, as when they say *walk the walk* and *talk the talk*. More
> specifically, **words derived from Latin that end in English in
> *-tion* nearly always name a process** and a result of that process:
> ‘abstraction’ (the process of abstracting something) alongside
> ‘an abstraction’, ‘construction’ (the business of building struc-
> tures) alongside ‘a construction’ (something built), and so on.
> In a related kind of word-use, the teacher of a cordon bleu
> cookery lesson hardly needs to explain that the French use the
> word cuisine to name the place where food is prepared (the
> kitchen) and the results of such preparation (*haute cuisine*,
> *cuisine bourgeoise*, etc.).

Page 22

[David Bellos gained his doctorate in French literature from Oxford University (UK) and taught subsequently at Edinburgh, Southampton and Manchester before coming to Princeton in 1997.](https://fit.princeton.edu/people/david-bellos). [*Is That a Fish in Your Ear? Translation and the Meaning of Everything*](https://cdn.waterstones.com/special/pdf/9780241954300.pdf)

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539393/what-determines-the-addition-of-the-suffixes-tion-and-sion - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/word-formation-with-the-nominal-suffix-tion-when-and-why-do-we-insert-an-a

Comment: Does the OP have any evidence for their claim that -tion always names the result of a process". There are lots of -tion words that can refer to action or process (action, levitation, deletion, hesitation, transaction, presentation, motion, interpolation, ...)

Comment: @StuartF I'm just quoting a book. I haven't asked the author.